# Navigation drawer force close from activity, how to fix it?

Tags: java, android, drawerlayout

I have a navigation drawer that is placed on the main activity, but when I open activity main, app force closes immediately.

I combine the drawer layout attribute with `activity_main.xml`**[Edited]**

```
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".UtamaActivity"
        android:layoutDirection="locale">
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
   ...

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_nav"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_margin="15dp" />
    
            <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/header_nav"
                app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />
    
...

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I use the image button above to programmatically open the drawer layout.

```
drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_nav).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
```

and that is a program to manage the use of the drawer layout, I opened the drawer layout using the image button, but the problem I found was, I haven't entered the main activity, my app just forces close, how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Share the log cat. Why are you opening and closing at the same time, plus you missed something else.

Comment: can you elaborate your problems with logcat ?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1053)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layoutDirection="locale">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

   <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_nav"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/text_dark"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer">

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

//use this code to get drawer is open or not

```
drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
findViewById(R.id.btn_nav).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (drawerLayout .isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    } else {
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    }
    }
});
```

Comment: I will try this code, because the `DrawerLayout` I use is still inside the `RelativeLayout` tag

Comment: make drawer as a parent and use all other container inside drawer

Comment: in my opinion, there seems to be an error in your answer, when opening the app for the first time, the navigation view appears immediately without clicking a button and can't even be closed.

Comment: i just edit my answer please check use close drawer in start

Comment: I have changed it, but when I click the button immediately the app forces close. Logcat : `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT`

Comment: what gravity you are using for drawer can you please show your code

Comment: i just edited the xml code, you can see it now. I put the Navigation view in the `RelativeLayout` because it adjusts several other layouts, so I set the `alignParentStart = true`

Answer (score 0):

The root of your issue is the missing `android:layout_gravity` attribute on the `NavigationView` tag, so try the following

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_gravity = "start"
        ...
        ... />
```

Comment: Why can't I set `layout_gravity` in the navigation view component?

Comment: I am not sure if I am following your doubt, can you update the question with what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You are opening and closing the drawer simultaneously, in your code:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
```

You first called `drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);` and then immediately called `drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);`, when the programs runs, this will open the drawer and immediately closes the drawer.

What you have to do is simply remove `drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);`from your code above.